# Is this an example of a factory or strategy?

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, factory, strategy-pattern

Suppose the following class chooses at runtime among a given set of instantiated singleton objects resolved from a dependency injection container:

```
class myClass {

    private container;   // DI container

    function getMeAnObject(input) {
        switch(input) {
            case A: return this.container.get(singletonA);
            case B: return this.container.get(singletonB);
            // etc...
        }   
    }
}
```

In this example would `myClass` be an implementation of the Factory or Strategy implementation or neither? Why?

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort." What do _you_ think is the answer and why?

Answer (score 0):

Because the objective of the class is to return an object, I'd argue it's a factory. While a strategy might also return an object, I'd expect it to focus more on a particular aspect of behaviour.